# Adding a different quantity to intervals of an array. Avoding looping?

Tags: matlab

Say I have an array of values:

```
values = 1:100;
```

an array of indices:

```
interval_indices = [40 45 80];
```

and an array of quantities that I would like to add to the elements in `values`:

```
quantities_to_add = [5 -9 30];
```

I am looking for a compact expression in MATLAB (maybe using `accumarray`?) that allows me to add the elmements of `quantities_to_add` to the elements in `values` depending on the indices specified by `indices`.

If I were to do this manually:

```
values(1:interval_indices(1))                         = values(1:interval_indices(1)) + ...
                                                         quantities_to_add(1);
values(interval_indices(1):interval_indices(2))       = values(interval_indices(1):interval_indices(2)) + ... 
                                                         quantities_to_add(2);
% and so forth

values(interval_indices(end-1):interval_indices(end)) = values(interval_indices(end-1):interval_indices(end)) + ...
                                                         quantities_to_add(end);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDIT:

Actually, this is a much smarter and vectorized way of doing the same:

```
lastIndx=interval_indices(end);   
quantitiesVector=zeros(1,lastIndx);
quantitiesVector([1,interval_indices(1:end-1)+1])=[quantities_to_add(1) diff(quantities_to_add)];

newValues=[values(1:lastIndx)+cumsum(quantitiesVector),values(lastIndx+1:end)];
```

---

#### Previous answer:

One way of doing it is using `arrayfun` to generate a vector of quantities and then adding.

```
intervalLength=diff([0 indices]);
lastIndx=interval_indices(end);
quantities=cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)ones(1,intervalLength(x))*quantities_to_add(x),1:numel(indices),...
    'UniformOutput',false));

newValues=[values(1:lastIndx)+quantities, values(lastIndx+1:end)];
```

Comment: I tried your first answer and I think you need to replace the last line by: `newValues                           = values;
newValues(1:interval_indices(end))  = values(1:interval_indices(end))+quantiles;` to keep the size of the `newValues` the same as `values`. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: I've fixed it and also added a better solution.